# PowerShell - Rename several files in several folders with increment

Tags: powershell, rename, increment, auto-increment, directory

My quest is how I can change the name of each file in several folders at once and still use incrementation unique to the folder.

More specifically I want to rename the .jpg-files in folders e.g. named 1.1, 1.2, 1.3, ... , 99.1, ... to the same name as the folder + and extra extension '**.X**'; where X = 1,2,...,99.

E.g. if the folder 1.1 contains 3 files I would like to name them: 1.1.1.jpg, 1.1.2.jpg and 1.1.3.jpg.

I am new to PowerShell, but I thought I managed to solve the issue with the following code:

```
$i = 1
Get-ChildItem "C:\Users\Rename" -Recurse | Where {$_.extension -eq ".jpg"} | %{Rename-Item $_.FullName -Newname ($_.Directory.Name+'.{0}.jpg' -f $i++)}
```

However, the incrementation does of course not understand when the folders change...

I was wondering if anyone might have an elegant solution to this issue or if I will have to learn how to use if/for statements in PowerShell?

I am grateful for any answers! (Will also greatly appreciate tips with "for" etc. coding with PowerShell.)

/Eric

Answer (score 0):

Get your list of folder first, then loop through them, resetting $i to 1 each time:

```
$folders = Get-ChildItem "C:\Users\Rename" -Recurse | where {$_.PSIsContainer -eq $true} | select FullName

foreach ($folder in $folders) {

Set-Location $folder.FullName

$i = 1

Get-ChildItem -Filter "*.jpg" | % {Rename-Item $_.FullName -Newname ($_.Directory.Name+'.{0}.jpg' -f $i++)}
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much Gareth! This code worked perfectly for me and is also very pedagogical which I am very greatful for! Especially enlightening was the way you define the path for the folders with $folders. Thanks yet again! Will really help my further developement in PowerShell :)

Comment: @EricAckevall thanks, no problem. It could be streamlined a little but likely that'd be less obvious what exactly it's doing.